# Pandas DataFrame Groupby and Sum Into New DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a dataframe:

```
office  cost
ABC 20
XYZ 10
ABC 100
XYZ 50

grouped = df.groupby(['office'])
test = grouped.aggregate(np.sum)
```

when I load either grouped or test into a csv file, I see only only the sum of costs
Is there a way I can load both columns office and sum of cost into a new dataframe and then into csv?

```
ABC 120
XYZ  60
```

Answer (score 3):

`test.to_csv('/tmp/out')` writes

```
office,cost
ABC,120
XYZ,60
```

to `/tmp/out`. This shows both columns, the office and the sum of the cost.

Comment: Yes, can you please explain why print test.columns shows only one column?                 Index([u'cost'],dtype='object')

Comment: `test` is the result of a groupby/agg operation. Since the `groupby` operation is grouping by `office` values, the unique `office` values becomes the *index* of the DataFrame returned by the `agg` operation. So `test` is a DataFrame with just one column (the `cost`), and an index composed of `office` values.

Comment: If you wish for `test` to have two columns, you could convert the index into a column using `test.reset_index(inplace=True)`.